# php nginx max upload file size - unusual case

Tags: php, file-upload, nginx

I was going through number of pages in google and pretty much all answers associated with this in stackoverflow, bus still, can not get this thing working.

I can upload smaller then 2M files, but not any larger.

I am running Centos 6.2 with `PHP-FPM` (PHP 5.3.10) and `NGINX` (nginx version: nginx/1.0.12).

Now I got `client_max_body_size 10M;` in nginx.conf, in the http section.
I also got `upload_max_filesize = 8M` , `post_max_size = 8M` , `memory_limit = 128M`

usually in almost any answer to this question I have met, these changes helps for users.

Now I done some research, and made this script:

```
<?php
//ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '8M');
$max_upload   = (ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));
$max_post     = (ini_get('post_max_size'));
$memory_limit = (int) (ini_get('memory_limit'));

echo ('$max_upload ' . $max_upload);
echo ('$max_post ' . $max_post);
echo ('$memory_limit ' . $memory_limit);
?>
```

Now If I run in in server terminal - i get `$max_upload 8M $max_post 8M $memory_limit 128`
But if I run it via webserver (NGINX) - I get `$max_upload 2M $max_post 8M $memory_limit 128`

So my assumption is that its NGINXes problem, but yet again the only NGINX parameter regarding this matter is `client_max_body_size 10M;` , which is sec correctly and is placed in the right place in the config.

I am sorry if this is something obvious, or if there is something I have missed, would be glad if someone would point me to the right direction.

Cheers !

EDIT:

So we solved it with AlexeyKa's help. We looked up in `phpinfo`, and there it said that php was using different php.ini file. Some time ago I made a copy of php.ini into my home directory. And it turnes out that when (some time ago) I restarted php-fpm, it switched from /etc/php.ini file to /home/my-user/php.ini file. Essentially I renamed the /home/my-user/php.ini and restarted the php-fpm. This solved everything, as it switched to /etc/php.ini. I will try to this behavior further, and will update the post, just in case someone will have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be different php.ini used? One for php-cli and another for php-fpm?

Answer (score 0):

change in

/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf

and 
    `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` to be safe
and change where it has

upload_max_filesize = 2M

to whatever file size u want example

upload_max_filesize = 8M

then reload

```
/etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart
/etc/init.d/nginx reload
/etc/init.d/nginx restart
```